# VBA Left Function?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm relatively new to VBA and have some code I wrote that seems like it should be straightforward but is not behaving as expected. I am trying to separate my primary WorkSheet (GAWi) into three other worksheets (LWi, WMi, & OTi) based on the first letter in column H. Basically if the first letter is "L" I want that row to be copied and pasted onto sheet LWi and then deleted from the original sheet. Then if it is W it goes onto WMi and if it is A it goes onto OTi. It is functioning properly for the first two If statements (placing items that begin with L & W onto the correct sheets), but for the last one items that begin with P and 0 are also being placed onto sheet OTi. I'm at a complete loss, it seems pretty easy and I can't figure out where I went wrong. Any advice would be much appreciated, also I'm sure this code is pretty unelegant by most standards so any tips on how to shorten it would also be welcomed-I've just started getting into VBA in the last couple weeks. Thank so much!

```
  Sheets("GAWi").Select
    Columns("H:H").Select
    Dim lwr As Range
    Set lwr = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        For i = lwr.Cells.Count To 1 Step -1
        If Left(lwr.Item(i).Value, 1) = "L" Then
            lwr.Item(i).EntireRow.copy
            Sheets("LWi").Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            Sheets("GAWi").Select
            lwr.Item(i).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
        If Left(lwr.Item(i).Value, 1) = "W" Then
            lwr.Item(i).EntireRow.copy
            Sheets("WMi").Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            Sheets("GAWi").Select
            lwr.Item(i).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
        If Left(lwr.Item(i).Value, 1) = "A" Then
            lwr.Item(i).EntireRow.copy
            Sheets("OTi").Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            Sheets("GAWi").Select
            lwr.Item(i).EntireRow.Delete
    End If   Next i
```

Comment: your wording (_" but for the last one items that begin with P and 0 are also being placed onto sheet OTi"_) seems inconsistent with your last `If` code (`If Left(lwr.Item(i).Value, 1) = "A" Then`

Comment: Yes! It is inconsistent, I can not figure out why some items are showing up on sheet OTi that should not be there, I didn't know if I was missing something obvious here.

Comment: what should be the actual check to pass in order to write rows in sheet "OTi"?

Comment: You are checking every cell -- not just the cells in column H.

Comment: The first letter of Column H should be an A for the row to be written onto OTi. I just ran this again on my dataset and rows with "06BA" "05TA" and even the header row which has "Pot ID" in column H were written onto OTi

Comment: Your code would be easier to debug if you got rid of all those `Select` methods and references to `ActiveSheet`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's a main flaw in your logic: the use of `UsedRange`

despite being it a 2D range, its `Item()` property would act as if it were a 1D array with one row listed after another

so that were "A1:H10" (eight columns) the address of `UsedRange`, `UsedRange.Item(1)` would point to "A1", `UsedRange.Item(8)` would point to "H1" and `UsedRange.Item(9)` would point to "A2" …

so you have to loop through the cells of column H only

Then there's a coding flaw, which is the use of all those `Select`/`Selection`: get in the habit of **always** use explicit range reference qualified up to their parent worksheet and workbook
. This can be reached, for instance, with the use of `With... End With` construct

here's a possible code (explanations in comments):

```
Option Explicit

Sub TransferRows()
    Dim i As Long

    With Sheets("GAWi") ' reference "source" sheet
        For i = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1 ' loop backwards from referenced sheet column H last not empty cell row index to 1
            Select Case UCase(.Cells(i, "H").Value) ' check for referenced sheet column H current row content
                Case "L"
                    TransferRow Intersect(.UsedRange, .Rows(i)), Sheets("LWi") ' pass referenced sheet current row "used" range and "LWi" destination sheet to the helper sub
                Case "W"
                    TransferRow Intersect(.UsedRange, .Rows(i)), Sheets("WMi") ' pass referenced sheet current row "used" range and "WMi" destination sheet to the helper sub
                Case "A"
                    TransferRow Intersect(.UsedRange, .Rows(i)), Sheets("OTi") ' pass referenced sheet current row "used" range and "OTi" destination sheet to the helper sub
            End Select
        Next i
    End With
End Sub

Sub TransferRow(sourceRng As Range, destSht As Worksheet)
    With destSht
        .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(, sourceRng.Columns.Count).Value = sourceRng.Value
    End With
    sourceRng.Delete xlUp
End Sub
```

As you see, other than the amendements due to the preface explanations I put in there:

- the use of `Select Case` syntax instead of `If Then End If`

  which I think is much clearer and would also correct a minor logic flaw of your orginal code: once a check is positive there's no need to run other ones (this you could have obtained by means of `If - Then - ElseIf - Endif` construct)
- the use of a "helper" sub to demand the repetitive code to

  which gives you much more control over your code and helps its maintenance
- the use of Cells(Rows.Count, colIndex).End(xlUp) pattern

  which is the most frequently used one to get the reference to the last not empty cell in some `colIndex` (be it a number or a letter) column

Comment: Thanks so much for the detail in this response and pointing out those logic flaws which were messing me up! I wanted to stick with using the If function just since I'm familiar with it. I cleaned the macro up a lot and think I made it pretty concise and got rid of those logic flaws, I posted what I did in an answer.

Comment: You are welcome. And I'd strongly advice you to try and follow those coding practices I showed you for your further progressing. Good coding

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to HTH's great response I was able to clean up my code a bit and think I got it figured out. I opted to stick with the `If Then Else If` format since I am not too familiar with using `Case` yet. Here's the first section of it, I just repeated the `copy, paste, delete row` for each starting letter.

```
Set rng = Range("GAWi!H:H")
        For k = rng.Cells.Count To 1 Step -1

            If Left(rng.Item(k).Value, 1) = "W" Then
                With rng.Item(k)
                    .EntireRow.copy
                    Sheets("WMi").Activate
                    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
                    .EntireRow.Delete
                End With

                ElseIf Left(rng.Item(k).Value, 1) = "L" Then....
```

This is running well for my purposes but if anyone has more suggestions they are much appreciated.